# Delete inside destructor call

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

In the following code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    Derived* d;

public:
    ~Derived()
    {    
        delete d;
    }
    Derived():d(NULL){}
};


int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

does the call `delete d;` inside Derived destructor lead to recursion in destructor calls?

Comment: Yes as long as `d is != nullptr`. Else `delete nullptr;` is no-op.

Comment: Depends on how `d` is initialised; if to `this`, then yes, if to another object (e.g. in a chain), then maybe not (depends on the chain).

Comment: Yes, it does. This is an archetypical example of a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no, there is no invocation of any destructor except the one in main.

[Reference on delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)

> If expression is not a null pointer, the delete expression invokes the
>   destructor (if any) for the object that's being destroyed, or for
>   every element of the array being destroyed (proceeding from the last
>   element to the first element of the array).

This leads me to think that since d is NULL, then the destructor will not be called. delete will execute but will return without performing anything significant.

Also this is very easy to test by adding a `std::cout` statement in every destructor

Answer (score 1):

The destructor

```
 Derived::~Derived() {    
        delete d;
   }
```

does not fall into recursion as d is a pointer to different Derived object and not same as this (current object), so even if `Derived::~Derived()` gets called, that's called for a different object, and eventually stops when d is NULL somewhere in the chain.